# laptop screen blank, kernel log full of EDID errors

Tags: linux, display

Since a week the laptop screen is blank. If I plug in an external monitor it works ok.

`dmesg` shows a couple of these error messages a minute:

```
kernel: [...] nouveau E[     DRM] DDC responded, but no EDID for LVDS-1
```

Googling tells that the EDID data is read from the screen to find out its display capabilities. In my case it seems to have been corrupted. There is a *lot* of discussion about various ways to fix it but I'm having trouble finding anything definite.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution on the [freedesktop.org bugtracker](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73267#c2) involving rewriting the EDID data over the i2c bus.

There is an alternative fix described [on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_mode_setting#Forcing_modes_and_EDID) but it required access to the windows driver or else creating an arcane kernel command line to override the EDID query.

**warning** : This is a pretty advanced technique. You need to understand hex dumps, be comfortable with the notion of writing to hardware addresses, and be able to understand what is going on when running the various commands shown. There are a couple of points where things don't work as they should - while I show the workrounds I used I don't explain them as this would take up too much space - you need to be able to understand what is going on in order to be able to modify the approach as needed for your situation.

**warning** : This involves poking around at a byte level over the i2c bus. You can irretrievably damage equipment this way. If your monitor is already not working you may not have much to loose, but if you get the i2c bus number wrong you may end up doing things to the external monitor.

---

Download [edid-tool](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=91473), compile it

```
wget https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=91473
mv attachment.cgi\?id\=91473 edid-tool.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O edid-tool.c
mv a.out edid-tool
```

install some packages - on debain based distros you need:

```
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools libi2c-dev
```

Then install the kernel module:

```
sudo modprobe i2c-dev
```

You now should have `/dev/i2c-1`, `/dev/i2c-2`... corresponding to i2c bus 1, 2 etc

Next task is to figure out which i2c bus the affected screen is on. See the linked bug report for details - basically  which look someting like:

```
for i in `ls /dev/i2c-*` ; do echo ; echo $i ; sudo ./edid-tool $i read ; done

/dev/i2c-1
           0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9  a  b   c  d  e  f   0123 4567 89ab cdef 
00000000  00 00 00 00  00 07 4f 00  06 10 bb 9c  00 00 00 00  |.... ..O. .... ....|
00000010  00 13 01 03  80 21 15 78  0a 50 c5 98  58 52 8e 27  |.... .!.x .P.. XR.'|
00000020  25 50 54 00  00 00 01 01  01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01  |%PT. .... .... ....|
00000030  01 01 01 01  01 01 7c 2e  90 a0 60 1a  1e 40 30 20  |.... ..|. ..`. .@0 |
00000040  36 00 4b cf  10 00 00 18  00 00 00 01  00 06 10 30  |6.K. .... .... ...0|
00000050  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  0a 20 00 00  00 fe 00 4c  |.... .... . .. ...L|
00000060  50 31 35 34  57 45 33 2d  54 4c 42 31  00 00 00 fe  |DELL 2001 TLB1 ....|
00000070  00 43 6f 6c  6f 72 20 4c  43 44 0a 20  20 20 00 dd  |.Col or L CD.    ..|

/dev/i2c-2
           0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9  a  b   c  d  e  f   0123 4567 89ab cdef 
00000000  ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff  36 74 30 00  01 00 00 00  |.... .... 6t0. ....|
00000010  0a 16 01 03  80 73 41 78  0a cf 74 a3  57 4c b0 23  |.... .sAx ..t. WL.#|
00000020  09 48 4c 21  08 00 81 80  45 40 61 40  95 00 01 01  |.HL! .... E@a@ ....|
00000030  01 01 01 01  01 01 02 3a  80 18 71 38  2d 40 58 2c  |.... ...: ..q8 -@X,|
00000040  45 00 c4 8e  21 00 00 1e  66 21 50 b0  51 00 1b 30  |E... !... f!P. Q..0|
00000050  00 70 26 44  c4 8e 21 00  00 1e 00 00  00 fc 00 4d  |.p&D ..!. .... ...M|
00000060  53 74 61 72  20 44 65 6d  6f 0a 20 20  00 00 00 fd  |Star  Dem o.   ....|
00000070  00 32 4b 1e  50 17 00 0a  20 20 20 20  20 20 01 fd  |.2K. P...        ..|
WARN at 209: Bad header: 0x0000 0000 0007 4f00
WARN at 217: Bad checksum: 0x5c

/dev/i2c-3
ERROR at 72: i2c_smbus_read_byte_data() failed: No such device or address
```

The screen with the issue will probably show `bad checksum` and `bad header` errors. Plus there may be details of the manufacturer in the text - in this case there was a Dell external monitor on `i2c-1` and the laptop's broken internal screen was on `i2c-2`.

The rest of the solution will use `/dev/i2c-2` - *do not blindly copy this* - see the above how to figure out which device you need to use.

Next output the current EDID data:

```
~ $ sudo ./edid-tool /dev/i2c-2 read > edid-bad
          0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9  a  b   c  d  e  f   0123 4567 89ab cdef 
00000000  ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff  |.... .... .... ....|
....
```

Now use the tool to fix the data:

```
~ $ sudo ./edid-tool /dev/i2c-2 fix < edid-bad > edid-fixed
          0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9  a  b   c  d  e  f   0123 4567 89ab cdef 
00000000  00 ff ff ff  ff ff ff 00  ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff  |.... .... .... ....|
....
```

This shows that the corrupt EDID data has `ff` at bytes `0x00` and `0x07` where it should have `0x00`

Validate the generated data by using `parse-edid` to output an `Xorg.conf` section:

```
$ parse-edid <edid-fixed 
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "�
                 @"
ModelName "�
                @"
VendorName "___"
# Monitor Manufactured week 0 of 2006
# EDID version 1.3
# Digital Display
DisplaySize 330 210
Gamma 2.20
Option "DPMS" "false"
Modeline    "Mode 0" 68.94 1280 1296 1344 1408 800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync 
EndSection
```

Check the `Modeline` matches your screen's display characteristics.

Now we *should* be able to load the fixed data with

```
sudo ./edid-tool /dev/i2c-2 write < edid-fixed
```

but it didn't work for the poster in the bug report or for me.

However there is a way to patch individual values on the i2c bus:

```
~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 2
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

This shows where the edid data is located - at bytes `0x50` through `0x57`.

We need to check the data right at the start of that, so we do this:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ; do echo -n "0x0$i  " ;  sudo i2cget -y 2 0x50 0x0"$i" b ; done
0x01  0x00
0x02  0xff
0x03  0xff
0x04  0xff
0x05  0xff
0x06  0xff
0x07  0xff
```

ok so it looks like `edid-tool` fixed the first byte, but failed to fix the one at `0x07`.

So we set this by:

```
sudo i2cset -y 2 0x50 0x07 0x00 b
```

So now we have the correct data. But the monitor still doesn't work. Run this again:

```
sudo ./edid-tool /dev/i2c-2 read > edid-bad
00000000  00 ff ff ff  ff ff ff 00  ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff  |.... .... .... ....|
...
00000070  00 4c 54 4e  31 35 34 58  41 2d 4c 30  31 0a 00 a0  |.LTN 154X A-L0 1...|
Error : bad checksum
```

Compare this output against the output of `edid-tool ... fix` and I see that the very last byte differs.

So I fix this with:

```
sudo i2cset -y 2 0x50 0x7f 0xc8 b
```

immediately the monitor comes back to life.